# Why the value of respose.data is null?

Tags: flutter, dart

Use dart to send a request, print response.data is null, but the status code is 200 OK

```
{
    const targetUrl = 'https://music.163.com/weapi/personalized/playlist';

    final reqData = {
      'limit': 30,
      'total': true,
      'n': 1000,
    };

    final encryptReqData = weapi(reqData);

    return {
      'success': (fn) async {
        Dio dio = Get.find<Dio>();
        Response response = await dio.post(targetUrl,
            data: encryptReqData,
            options: Options(
              headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                'User-Agent':
                    'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 8.1.0; zh-cn; BLA-AL00 Build/HUAWEIBLA-AL00) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/57.0.2987.132 MQQBrowser/8.9 Mobile Safari/537.36',
              },
            ));
        final playlists = [];
        print(encryptReqData);
        print(response.data.toString());
        print(response.statusMessage);
        json.decode(response.data).result.forEach((item) {
          final playlist = {
            'cover_img_url': item.picUrl,
            'id': "neplaylist_${item.id}",
            'source_url': "https://music.163.com/#/playlist?id=${item.id}",
            'title': item.name,
          };
          playlists.add(playlist);
        });
        return fn({
          'status': 'success',
          'data': {
            playlists,
          },
        });
      },
    };
  }
```

Use postwoman to send a request with the same parameters and return data
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/apqp7.png)

Trying to use postwoman to send a request, but got the data, looking forward to using dart to get the data

Comment: In the postman you're sending `params` and `encSecKey`, did you forget to add them?

Comment: No, the encryptReqData contains params and encSecKey